# Compare Arrays with jQuery.grep() JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I am struggling a bit with $.grep and comparing Arrays.
It's a specific question so I'll try to keep it as simple as possible.

I've got an Array with a list of Shops which contain a list of extras.
e.G toilet, wifi and coffee. [toilet: "1", wifi: "0", coffee: "0"]

And I've got input fields (checkbox).

```
var extras = [];
$(".input-extra").on("change", function(e){
    if(this.checked){
        extras.push(this.name);
    }else{
        extras.remove(this.name);
    }
});
```

If I check an input checkbox field, my Array will get filled with the name of the input field (e.g "toilet")

Now I'd like to display shops which agree with my input fields. (Sorry, I don't know how to discribe it better, so I posted some examples)

e.G shop1 offers coffee and wifi. I'm looking for shops with wifi.
So shop 1 will be displayed.

shop2 offers coffee and a toilet. I'm looking for shops with wifi.
shop 2 won't be displayed.
That works fine: but how can I embed extras?

```
function fillShopListFilter(data, zip, extras, pricemin, pricemax, squaremetermin, squaremetermax) {

    var length = $.grep(shortShopList.shops, function( n, i ) {
        return zip.includes(parseInt(n.zip)) && parseInt(n.price)>=pricemin && parseInt(n.price)<=pricemax && parseInt(n.squaremeter)>=squaremetermin && parseInt(n.squaremeter)<=squaremetermax;
    });
.....
}
```

I think that's clear.

Thanks for EVERY answer.

Comment: Can you also post your current code for updating shop list along with the html placeholder for shop list.

Comment: I'm getting all shops via Ajax as a JSON object. (REST API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it by myself.

```
var length = $.grep(shortShopList.shops, function( n, i ) {
    return zip.includes(parseInt(n.zip)) && parseInt(n.price)>=pricemin && parseInt(n.price)<=pricemax && parseInt(n.squaremeter)>=squaremetermin && parseInt(n.squaremeter)<=squaremetermax;
});

var newlength = $.grep(length, function( n, i ) {
    var x = 0;
    $.each(n.extras, function (indexInArray, element) { 
        if(extras.includes(indexInArray) && parseInt(element) == 1){
            x++;
        }
    });
    return x == extras.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery grep:

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

```
var extras = [];
$(".input-extra").on("change", function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    extras.push(this.name);
  } else {
    extras = $.grep(extras, function(extra) {
      return extra != this.name;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help me in any way.